# Update SQL with txt file in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I put together with help of the internet some code in php. I'm not very good at php I want to update SQL table from txt file store on different page

The txt file has a structure like this:

```
1006704;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;198861;198861;198861;198861;198861;198861
1006705;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;98871;98871;98871;98871;98871;98871
1006709;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;48876;48876;48876;48876;48876;48876
```

and here is the php:

```
<?php  

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','something','pass');
if (!$connect) {
die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
}

$cid =mysql_select_db('database',$connect);

$text = file_get_contents('http://somedomainname/stock/something.txt');
$text = explode("\n",$text);
foreach($text as $line)
{
$temp = explode('Macma_Item_No:',$line);
$Macma_Item_No = explode(";",$temp[0]);
$temp = explode('Local_Inventory:',$line);
$Local_Inventory = explode(";",$temp[0]);
$temp = explode('Local_Future_2:',$line);
$Local_Future_2 = explode(";",$temp[0]);
$temp = explode('Local_Future_3:',$line);
$Local_Future_3 = explode(";",$temp[0]);
$temp = explode('Local_Future_4:',$line);
$Local_Future_4 = explode(";",$temp[0]);
$temp = explode('Local_Future_5:',$line);
$Local_Future_5 = explode(";",$temp[0]);
$temp = explode('Local_Future_6:',$line);
$Local_Future_6 = explode(";",$temp[0]);
$temp = explode('Inernational_Inventory:',$line);
$Inernational_Inventory = explode(";",$temp[0]);
$temp = explode('Inernational_Future_2:',$line);
$Inernational_Future_2 = explode(";",$temp[0]);
$temp = explode('Inernational_Future_3:',$line);
$Inernational_Future_3 = explode(";",$temp[0]);
$temp = explode('Inernational_Future_4:',$line);
$Inernational_Future_4 = explode(";",$temp[0]);
$temp = explode('Inernational_Future_5:',$line);
$Inernational_Future_5 = explode(";",$temp[0]);
$temp = explode('Inernational_Future_6:',$line);
$Inernational_Future_6 = explode(" ",$temp[0]);

$sql = "INSERT INTO oc_stock_international2 (Macma_Item_No,Local_Inventory,Local_Future_2,Local_Future_3,Local_Future_4,Local_Future_5,Local_Future_6,Inernational_Inventory,Inernational_Future_2,Inernational_Future_3,Inernational_Future_4,Inernational_Future_5,Inernational_Future_6) VALUES ('".$Macma_Item_No[0]."','".$Local_Inventory[0]."','".$Local_Future_2[0]."','".$Local_Future_3[0]."','".$Local_Future_4[0]."','".$Local_Future_5[0]."','".$Local_Future_6[0]."','".$Inernational_Inventory[0]."','".$Inernational_Future_2[0]."','".$Inernational_Future_3[0]."','".$Inernational_Future_4[0]."','".$Inernational_Future_5[0]."','".$Inernational_Future_6[0]."')";
mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

Right now in this state it succesfully write same data every column from the file but when I change separator to something different all the data is going be in the first column. I am sure its just some simple mistake and likely first one looking at this will figure this out but thank you all who is willing to help

Comment: as is see in your .txt file all value separate with `;` so try this `explode(";",$text);`

Comment: tried it got Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in  and empty table but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo need to change this part of code:

```
foreach($text as $line)
{
    $parts = explode(";", $line);
    $Macma_Item_No = $parts[0];
    $Local_Inventory = $parts[1];
    $Local_Future_2 = $parts[2];
    $Local_Future_3 = $parts[3];
    $Local_Future_4 = $parts[4];
    $Local_Future_5 = $parts[5];
    $Local_Future_6 = $parts[6];
    $Inernational_Inventory = $parts[7];
    $Inernational_Future_2 = $parts[8];
    $Inernational_Future_3 = $parts[9];
    $Inernational_Future_4 = $parts[10];
    $Inernational_Future_5 = $parts[11];
    $Inernational_Future_6 = $parts[12];
....
```

But this code is cleaner:

```
list($Macma_Item_No, $Local_Inventory, $Local_Future_2, 
     $Local_Future_3, $Local_Future_4, $Local_Future_5, 
     $Local_Future_6 ,$Inernational_Inventory, 
     $Inernational_Future_2, $Inernational_Future_3, 
     $Inernational_Future_4, $Inernational_Future_5, 
     $Inernational_Future_6) = explode(";", $line);
```

For the SQL part, change with this:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO oc_stock_international2 (Macma_Item_No,Local_Inventory,Local_Future_2,Local_Future_3,Local_Future_4,Local_Future_5,Local_Future_6,Inernational_Inventory,Inernational_Future_2,Inernational_Future_3,Inernational_Future_4,Inernational_Future_5,Inernational_Future_6) VALUES ('$Macma_Item_No', '$Local_Inventory', '$Local_Future_2', '$Local_Future_3', '$Local_Future_4', '$Local_Future_5', '$Local_Future_6', '$Inernational_Inventory', '$Inernational_Future_2', '$Inernational_Future_3', '$Inernational_Future_4', '$Inernational_Future_5', '$Inernational_Future_6')";
```

The SQL part

Some advises:

- Do not use *mysql_* functions because are deprecated and will be removed in php 7 so your code need to be rewritten. Use mysqli or PDO
- Use parametrized queries

UPDATE:

I changed the SQL part to add `$` to the last four columns and put `'` to the parameters to allow zeroes at the start.

Comment: i tried this only first collumn was filled others was empty i make mistake in the first post the result from the first one was same data in every collum in table

Comment: i forgot to edit the sql part -_- with you edit i was able to fill table with almost all data but the last tree collumns were empty strange i will double ceck it but it seems this will work

Comment: realy strange i have no idea why the last four columns arent transfered to the sql but even stranger thing is that rows that starting with zero like 09979001 are transfered in form of 9979001 without zeroes on start

Comment: i will update my code to support the zeroes, and for the last four columns i forgot the `$`, sorry, my fault

Comment: thank you very much working on 100% i still cannot believe that i did not seen those missing $ :) but thanks, you are awesome